# Why did this question get three review comments?

Tags: support, comments, review

The answer here [What if I forget to pay rent?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6459/what-if-i-forget-to-pay-rent/51420#51420) ended up with the auto comments (some of which aren't very friendly, but that's a separate matter).

I can't see on [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/27386) what the review responses were.

But this Meta question [Prevent duplicate auto-comments from review deletion recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143669/prevent-duplicate-auto-comments-from-review-deletion-recommendation) implies this shouldn't happen.

Why did it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Low Quality Posts review queue asks you, if you choose Delete or Recommend Deletion, if you want to leave one of five standard comments, corresponding to the most common situations where a (new) user posts an answer which is (by Stack Exchange standards) not an answer.

Apparently, three reviewers chose three *different* comments, so the duplicate comment prevention didn't apply. Anyway, the answer is now gone.